# Powerpoint VBA - move the inserted audio after the existing animation

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I have number of animations on a slide e.g 4 mainsequences. For each of animation, I want to insert relevent sound to start with the animation.

I have the following function:

```
Option Explicit

Function InsertAudio(lngIndex As Long, filepath As String) ' As String
    Dim oShp As Shape
    Dim oEffect As Effect
    Dim oSld As Slide

    ' Get current slide
    Set oSld = Application.ActiveWindow.View.Slide

    ' Add the audio shape
    Set oShp = oSld.Shapes.AddMediaObject2(filepath, msoFalse, msoTrue, 0, 0)
    DoEvents
    'Debug.Print lngIndex
    
    Set oEffect = oSld.TimeLine.MainSequence.AddEffect(oShp, msoAnimEffectMediaPlay, , msoAnimTriggerWithPrevious)
    With oEffect
        .MoveTo lngIndex + 1
        
        ' Hide effect icon in slideshow
        .EffectInformation.PlaySettings.HideWhileNotPlaying = True
        
        .Timing.TriggerDelayTime = 0
    End With
    Set oEffect = Nothing
    
    ' Move the shape outside the slide
    Call SetLocation(lngIndex, oShp)
    
End Function
```

The function insert the audio successfully but the command line `oEffect.MoveTo lngIndex + 1` doesn't move the inserted audio to the target index. The audio always inserted after all of the animation instead of after the corresponding animation. How to do move the inserted audio, say, after the 1st animation?

Comment: when you add the effect, there is a field for the index of the animation effects after `msoAnimTriggerWithPrevious`, have you tried using that? for example: `Set oEffect = oSld.TimeLine.MainSequence.AddEffect(oShp, msoAnimEffectMediaPlay, , msoAnimTriggerWithPrevious, lngIndex)`

Comment: Yes, the result is the same.
Is that because the existing animations (the first 4) are a "collection of animations" that animate 4 different paragraphs of text in a shape? Is it possible to insert a new animation between them?

Comment: I am having trouble with  `.EffectInformation.PlaySettings.HideWhileNotPlaying = True` (which should be `msoTrue` by the way). All the rest is running smooth but that part scrambles everything. Is it necessary to hide it, since you are then calling a function that moves the shape away from view? (`Call SetLocation(lngIndex, oShp)`)